# FFMPEG conversion from webm to mp4 intermittent on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-media-player, mp4, webm

I am trying to convert .webm file that we get from google's screencastify to .mp4 file. 
I need it to be playable using Windows Media Player. I need it the file to be playing with all the WMP versions from last 3 years and on Windows XP and Win 7.

I am using a Ubuntu 14.04 container for the same.

I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.webm -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -strict experimental out.mp4
```

Following are my observations:

1. The out.mp4 sometimes plays with the windows media player. At the time when it plays the time for conversion is less and file size is also normal.
2. Sometimes it just plays a black video. At that time it takes a lot of time for conversion.The file size in that case is also very high.
3. Longer videos do not play, shorter ones do. (Longer > 25 mins)

Console output:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 18:52:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:1.2.6-1~trusty1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    53.  5.103 / 53.  5.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/tmp/Untitled Screencast.webm':
  Duration: 00:11:51.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 666 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 992x736, SAR 1:1 DAR 31:23, 1k fps, 30.25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[libx264 @ 0x1526fe0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x1526fe0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x1526fe0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x1526fe0] 264 - core 142 r2491 24e4fed - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/448dfa6f-b118-44b9-a22f-fc763bbcdc5b.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 992x736 [SAR 1:1 DAR 31:23], q=-1--1, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp8 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (vorbis -> aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

Comment: Please show the complete `ffmpeg` console output that results from your command. Which WMP and Windows versions are you working with?

Comment: You still need to tell us which Windows version and which WMP versions you are targeting or you have tried.  Also, please clarify what "sometimes" means. Which videos play and which don't? What is the difference between them? (show conversion logs)

Comment: I am trying to convert it on Ubuntu 14.04. I need it the file to be playing with all the WMP versions from last 3 years and on Windows XP and Win 7.

Comment: Longer videos do not play, shorter ones do. (Longer > 25 mins)

Comment: Next time please add all the information in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the file to be playing on Windows XP, you cannot use H.264 video and AAC audio. Your least common denominator is whatever Windows Media Player 11 supports, which is the latest version you can get for XP.

Or you provide codecs with your video. Or a proper player, like VLC.

[See this chart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316992). The only video codec for which you don't need additional support is the very old MPEG-1. MP3 audio should work though.